# What if we include every UIScrollViewDelegate method in its UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, cocoa, delegates

I am learning the concept delegation. I know its definition and how it works in a few example.

What if we include every `UIScrollViewDelegate` method in its `UIScrollView`? We can still make it work, because if we can let `UIScrollView` act on itself, rather than send information to its delegate and wait for delegate's response.

Why don't we do so? Is it because `UIScrollView` would become massive? Is it because we want to `UIScrollView` to handle most general tasks and let its delegate handle some other minor tasks? Why this way is worse than delegation?

This question can be extended to a general question: what's the motivation of delegation in the context of iOS?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of delegation (in this context) is to let something else know about things that are happening. The scroll view already knows everything that is happening about itself. There is no reason for the scroll view to implement any of the delegate methods. The delegate methods are available so the scroll view can (optionally) tell its delegate about specific events so the delegate can react accordingly as needed.

A better example might be `UITableView`. It has a delegate and a data source. The point of the data source is so the table view can make a request to determine what and how much data to show. Its delegate is there to inform the delegate about various events happening with the table view. It would make no sense for the table view to implement all of those data source and delegate methods. The whole point is that the table view is generic and can show any amount of data with any content. It's the data source that provides the details of what to show.

Answer (score 1):

`UIScrollView` is really universal and is used heavily during iOS development. Scrolling is pretty simple and works basically the same everywhere. However, there are often situations when you want to add some behaviour to a scrollView just in one place. For example, each time when user scrolls content on main screen, you want to print message to console. You don't want to add this logic to `UIScrollView` because you only want this one scroll view to behave this way. By having ability to attach a delegate to `UIScrollView`, you can inject some specific behaviour to certain scrollView without changing other scrollView's behaviour.